# How can i check validation at the time of user hold off / leave edit text area

Tags: android

Here i have describe code about check validation at the time of user leave edittext focus...

```
    TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           // Check Condition

            } else {
```

// Check Condition

```
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    };

    // text watcher registration to the 2 EditText
    etEmail.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    etPassword.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    etUserName.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: The code you have provided is not for leaving the focus from edittext.

Comment: If you want to check the focus for edittext use `yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener`

Comment: How can i manage it... can u give me a ample demo projecyt for that...Plz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register an OnFocusChangeListener on your EditText inside your activity's onCreate method:

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
  et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
  {
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
  {
    if (!hasFocus)
        // TODO: the editText has just been left
  }
});
```

Here the v parameter of the onFocusChange is your EditText control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example,

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
});
```